# PHP Codeigniter : set Port Number for MySQL Configuration

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Can you explain to me how to set port number  for a Database configuration :

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model 
{
    protected static $db2_loaded = false;
    protected static $db2 = false;
    function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if(($this->session->userdata('login_user')!=false) && !self::$db2_loaded) 
        { 
            self::$db2_loaded = true;
            $config['hostname'] = "localhost";      
            $config['username'] = "root";
            $config['password'] = "";
            $config['database'] = $this->session->userdata('bdd_compte');
            $config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
            $config['dbprefix'] = "";
            $config['pconnect'] = TRUE;
            $config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
            $config['cache_on'] = FALSE;
            $config['cachedir'] = "";
            $config['char_set'] = "utf8";

            $config['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
            self::$db2 = $this->load->database($config,TRUE);

        }
        $this->db = self::$db2;


    }
}
```

Any ideas how should I set a different port number

Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the `port` key in `database.php`.

```
$db['default']['port'] = 5432;
```

OR

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "mysqlhost.yourdomain.com:3310";
```

Comment: `$db['default']['port'] = 5432;` didn't work, 
went with: 
`$db['default']['hostname'] = "mysqlhost.yourdomain.com:3310";  `

Comment: It's not listed at the first comment that shows all the possibles parameters.

Answer (score -1):

this work

$db['default'] = array(
    'hostname' => '99.99.99.99:3337',

Comment: If you are providing answer to the question I suggest using variables and setup from code sample that was asked in the question. This answer while it could be correct it does not  show how it answers the problem with sample code in original question. I suggest copying sample code from original question and adding your solution to it.